# Which is better and why ? element.onclick = function() Versus AddEventListener()

Tags: javascript

I kinda got used to using this sample method to fire functions..
I need advices on which method should I more likely use and why..

```
var Div    = document.getElementById("Div");
            newDivX.onClick = function()
            {
                alert("done");
            }
```

Comment: @Jack I see great use cases for touch enabled devices.

Comment: If you want to learn about the different ways of attaching event handlers, I recommend to read these articles: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html